# Beautifulsoup4 unclosed tag bug

Tags: parsing, beautifulsoup

In parsing "link" tags, soup was not understand unslashed tag.

example...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<html>
        <head>
        <title>bs4bug</title>
          <link rel="1"/>
          <link rel="2">
          <link rel="3"/>
          <link rel="4"/>
          <link rel="5"/>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>bs4bug</h1>
          <link rel="6"/>
        </body>
        </html>'

for num, link in enumerate(BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser').findAll('link'), start=1):
    print(num, link)
```

Output:

```
1 <link rel="1"/>
2 <link rel="2"/>
3 <link rel="3"><link rel="4"/><link rel="5"/></link>
4 <link rel="4"/>
5 <link rel="5"/>
6 <link rel="6"/>
```

in my case it hapen after this line:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Rubik:400,500,700,300&amp;subset=latin" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

bs4, was wrap all html in one unclosed tag "link".

How to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

To correctly parse the document, use **`lxml`** or **`html5lib`** parser:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html>
        <head>
        <title>bs4bug</title>
          <link rel="1"/>
          <link rel="2">
          <link rel="3"/>
          <link rel="4"/>
          <link rel="5"/>
        </head>
        <body>
          <h1>bs4bug</h1>
          <link rel="6"/>
        </body>
        </html>"""

sup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")  # <-- use `lxml` or `html5lib`
for num, link in enumerate(sup.findAll("link"), start=1):
    print(num, link)
```

Prints:

```html
1 <link rel="1"/>
2 <link rel="2"/>
3 <link rel="3"/>
4 <link rel="4"/>
5 <link rel="5"/>
6 <link rel="6"/>
```

Comment: bs4 is most popular it's why i was choose it. thanks for answer. i will look again at this library

Comment: @AlikSei Yes, but replace `'html.parser'` with `lxml` or `html5lib`. That's what `bs4` uses internally to parse the HTML document

Comment: Cool, 'html5lib' solve my stuck! but 'lxml' same as 'bs4'. Thanks a lot!